# NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton = false has no effect

Tags: maui

I try to disable the BackButton in a contentPage. I found that NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton= false must be the solution. So I try it, unsucessfully.I found a topic (NavigationPage.HasBackButton property not working in Windows 11) on https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/4407. The topic is closed with the status resolved.But, I use Windows 10 (Net 7) and the problem is always present.start a new very simple project to show the problem : so I put NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton in
AppShell :

```cs
public AppShell()
{     
   InitializeComponent();

   NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false);

   Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(AutrePage), typeof(AutrePage));     
}
```

and also in the caller (MainPage) :

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"x:Class="MauiAppTestNoBackButton.MainPage"NavigationPage.HasBackButton="False">
```

and the receiver (AutrePage) that is called by :

```cs
private void GotoAway_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(AutrePage));
}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiAppTestNoBackButton.AutrePage"
             NavigationPage.HasBackButton="False"
             Title="AutrePage">
```

Have you a suggestion ?
Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is using `OnBackButtonPressed` in your ContentPage.

```cs
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
{
    // Return true to prevent back button 
    return true;
}
```

And if you want to remove the back button you use `Shell.BackButtonBehavior` in your xaml.

```xml
<Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
    <BackButtonBehavior
        IsVisible="False" />
</Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
```

To not leave anything out, you can naturally disable the back button with behaviour as well.

```xml
<Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
    <BackButtonBehavior
        IsEnabled="False" />
</Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
```

Comment: Whaouuu !!! Simple ! and it try it .... YESSS it solves my problem. Thanks to you Peter

Comment: Don't forget to set this as answer if this it working for you. By doing this you are helping others to find an answer if they are in a similar situation.